# Is watermarking my unique images sufficient

Tags: images

I have a bunch of unique images on my website.

- Should I watermark them?  Is that a sufficient deterrent against blatant copying?
- Should I make them difficult to download?

Comment: Nothing will stop people getting your images.  If they are displayed on the web they can be downloaded.  A watermark might deter some people, but there are others who won't care.  One solution is to show low-resolution images that aren't worth stealing, but that might defeat the purpose of even having them on your site